Unable to edit copied images from other sources with GIMP
I am unable to open and edit copied images from other sources (phone, other PC). I am using Gimp and Ubuntu 24.04 LTS. Image viewer opens those normally. Just getting a message 'permission denied'.
By default copied images get rw-rw-r-- and containing folders drwxrwxr-x. Ownership/group is mine.
I even tried to run sudo gimp and got:
mkdir: cannot create directory '/run/user/0': Permission denied
Authorization required, but no authorization protocol specified
Cannot open display:

Why is this happening, does anyone have a clue?
Edit: So, GIMP can't read anything from mounted 2Tb HDD, nor it can be started with sudo.

Explore your Mount/Read/Write/Execute problems with https://github.com/waltinator/pathlld, a bash script to show the permissions, mount options along the path to an object or objects.

Where is the files located? How is gimp installed?

I bypassed, not solved the problem with another app.
GIMP can't read anything on mounted 2Tb HDD. Copied file in SSD with same permissions it opens. I think it was installed by App Center, though I mostly use snap with 24.04 or apt.
